# Flutter Admob VideoReward dose not work on real life apps

Tags: flutter, admob

I just published an app before I realized that it does not work as expected.

I followed the example in Flutter's Admob and I can see the test video add. I replaced it with my ad unit and keep using test device also works. Replace testDevice with appID and configure app logic, publish the app and no video ads.

I wonder here what can be wrong? Can somebody provide working example or even tell if it really works?

Answer (score 0):

Well I know I am late, but for someone who also has this same error,
You don't need to replace test Device with appID, testDevice is for the emulator, on real devices you don't need to specify anything it will work automatically!